# Store serialized object together with it's simpler variant in C#

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a large class of ~90ish variables like so:

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class myLargeClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int BetId { get; set; }

    ...

    [ProtoMember(95)]
    public string someVariable { get; set; }
}
```

I have a large amount of these objects that I save to my disk for my application. This is serialized using protobuf into one large list and placed on my disk locally.

```
List<myLargeClass>
```

The idea is that instead of deserializing the entire thing into the big class, I have made a simpler version that only contains a subset of the variables. But also the byte[] of the serialized large object, such that I can access all the variables in case I need it:

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class mySmallerClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public bool someVariable { get; set; }

    public byte[] largeObject { get; set; }
}
```

My current solution is slow in that I serialize both into the small and large class:

```
var smallObjects = Serializer.Deserialize<List<mySmallerClass>>(data);
var largeObjects = Serializer.Deserialize<List<myLargeClass>>(data);

Parallel.ForEach(smallObjects, (object) =>
{
    var x = largeObjects.Where(b => b.Id == object.Id).Single();
    object.largeObject = Crypto.Serialize(x);
});
```

This solution is very slow especially when you have hundreds of thousands or millions of objects.

How do I efficiently get the large objects serialization into the smaller object?

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

> I have a large amount of these objects

you do a lot of lookups in `List` which is `O(n)` complexity. Convert `List` to `Dictionary` and then get object by `Id`:

```
var largeObjects = Serializer.Deserialize<List<myLargeClass>>(data).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
...
var x = largeObjects[object.Id];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was more wondering if there was a way to do it, without having to deserialize the large class and then serializing it again.

Comment: @Cralle It could be the next step of optimization. But you should start from the obvious one. Did you measure what part is the slowest (deserialization or lookups)? You definitely should try approach with `Dictionary` and report back the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the small data, `mySmallerClass` without the extra blob field is fine. If you need to be able to "round trip" fields you don't track, however:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class mySmallerClass : Extensible
{
    ...
}
```

Note also that protobuf-net doesn't look for, or care about, `[Serializable]`.